# no se muestra el control ReportViewer en VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2015, reportviewer, visual-studio-2017

Estoy trabajando con visual Studio 2017. agregue a un formulario un control ReportViewer y este no se muestra en el formulario en si.

Veo que la solución agrega las referencias necesarias, el control se ve en el esquema del documento y me agrega una barra inferior imagino que para controlar los reportes que muestra, pero el control en si en el formulario permanece ausente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

E intentado agregar el control  desde extensiones y actualizaciones, agregando el diseñador de informes RDLC de Microsoft. También desde el administrador de paquetes NuGet agregando Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms y luego agregando su libreria al proyecto pero en ambos casos el resultado es el mismo, no se visualiza el control.

Ya hay algunas preguntas creadas relacionadas a esto, sin embargo ninguna tiene solución aun, quizá era necesario ser mas explicito. alguien tiene alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Incluyo esta imagen mostrando que el control esta disponible en el IDE.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Incluyo la vista de elementos para agregar en el toolbox.

Comment: Editalo con visual 2010, arrastra el control al formulario y listo. Luego lo abres con visual 2017.
Tuve exactamente el mismo problema. Saludos, espero les sirva.

Comment: A mi también me pasaba lo mismo, instala visual studio 2015. [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8aDi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8aDi.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Instale la extensión para Visual Studio 2017
   [Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqlReportingServices.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001)
2. Instale las bibliotecas en su proyecto
   [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms/140.802.134-rc)
3. Añade la referencia de la biblioteca descargable por NuGet a Toolbox 
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Ahora seleccione la biblioteca descargable por NuGet
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Listo!
Sólo tienes que seleccionar y arrastrar a tu formulario!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La extención Microsoft RDLC ya la tenia instalada. Las bibliotecas que me proporcionaste son posteriores a las que tenia, ya actualice (Gracias) pero aun así, no puedo ver el control dentro del formulario. `El paquete 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms.140.340.80' se quitó de la carpeta ` `El paquete 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms.140.802.134-rc' se agregó a 'packages.config'
'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms 140.802.134-rc' se instaló correctamente `

Comment: En Visual Studio 2017 tuve que añadir manualmente el control ReportViewer en la barra de herramientas (Toolbox), vea el paso 3.

Comment: Si, se debe hacer manual y como ves en mi imagen, el problema no esta en si en ver el control en el toolbox, el problema es que al arrastrarlo al formulario, lo incluye en el esquema del documento, pone la barra inferior mostrándolo como reportViewer1 y deja el formulario sin cambios, no agrega los controles de interfaz que tu pones en tus instrucciones. Incluí una nueva imagen tratando de mostrarlo.

Comment: Como trabajo con Report Viewer bastante tiempo, he instalado: 
MICROSOFT REPORT VIEWER 2015 RUNTIME, 
MICROSOFT REPORT VIEWER 2010 RUNTIME. 
Por el icono que veo en la imagen de su pregunta, su versión debe ser 10.0.0.0.

Comment: Si e probado con la versión 10. pero también se actualizo, en este momento la versión en uso es la 14. (edite la pregunta para incluir foto de ello). Temo que la solución sera des instalar y reinstalar el IDE?

Comment: Cree un proyecto con un formulario, utilice la versión más actualizada del Framework .Net y vea si funciona.

Comment: Tiene el mismo comportamiento, no se si sea importante mencionar que en el esquema del documento me lo deja al mismo nivel que el form y no dentro de el.

Comment: aunque hacer lo mismo esperando un resultado diferente sea la definición de locura, des instale complementos y lo volví a intentar de 0.... funciono. gracias!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64263/discussion-between-german-at-and-edvaldo-silva).

Answer (score 0):

Amigo la solución como comentas es volviendo a rehacer el procedimiento, pero trata de hacerlo ahora de otra forma:

1- Elimina si ya tienes ReportViewer del cuadro de herramientas de VS2017

2- Abre la consola del administrador de paquetes (Menu Herramientas / Administrador de paquetes NuGet / Consola del administrador de paquetes)

3- copia y pega el siguiente comando:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WinForms
```

4- Agrega el control al cuadro de herramientas ReportViewer de nueva cuenta.

5- Vuelve a agregarlo a tu winform e intenta nuevamente.

[Te dejo enlace del procedimiento que aplica para webforms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-2017), suerte amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción diferente seria la siguiente:

1) Instalar la extensión para Visual Studio 2017

```
Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer
```

[image: Ubicación de la extensión]

Luego nos dirigimos a Online y en el buscador escribimos el nombre de la  extensión

[image: Instalación de la extensión]

2) Instala la biblioteca en su proyecto

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms.v12
```

[image: Ubicación de la biblioteca]

Procurar que sea la versión para WinForms

[image: Instalación de la biblioteca]

3) Agregamos la biblioteca en el cuadro de herramientas

[image: Ubicación donde agregar la biblioteca]

Dentro de nuestro proyecto buscamos el archivo de la biblioteca

[image: Ubicación del archivo]

Con todo esto ya estaría listo para trabajar